# How many unique conditions can be defined using only two on and off mode switches?

Tags: binary, cpu, computer-science, cpu-architecture

I am trying to figure this out, how many conditions can be defined using two switches? assuming switch have two modes of on and off.
Are there any formulas to calculate the number of unique answers, based on number of devices? or resources to read?

Comment: Use math.  Example: how many different values with one decimal digit? 10 . With two?  100.  With three? 1000.  Generalize with formula. Do same exercise with base 2 / binary.

Comment: Infinite. Use the first switch as a trigger (clock), and second as data channel.